# Differing URL between submit button value and reality

Tags: php, get

I'm building a stripped-down CMS for a school project, and am running into issues regarding deleting a user.

On the site admin page, which is only accessible via an `admin` login name and related password, a table of existing users is populated.  Each row displays vital stats about the user, as well as a Delete button.

As this admin page is the same URL as the regular user admin page, I've used the echo statement to  write out the table elements only if the login is the admin.  The button calls a function in an external script via a GET request and attaches the userID to the URL.

At least thats what is supposed to happen.  According to Firebug, the button element has the following attributes:

```
<form id="deleteUser" method="get" action="includes/scripts.php?action=deleteUser&id=18" name="deleteUser">
<input type="submit" value="Delete" name="submit">
```

However, when clicking on the button above, I get the URL

```
http://localhost/TestingLab/admin/includes/scripts.php?submit=Delete
```

Whats the deal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submitting a GET form will trash any existing query string.

Move the data to hidden inputs instead.

```
<form id="deleteUser" method="get" action="includes/scripts.php">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="deleteUser">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value=18">
<input type="submit" value="Delete" name="submit">
```

… but don't change things on the server based on a GET request. GET requests are supposed to be repeatable and safe. Use POST.

Comment: What do you mean by trashing an existing query string?

Comment: If you have a query string in the URL in the action attribute then it won't be there when you submit the form.